# ReactJS/Firebase: specify document name or "id" on creation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Where do I specify the name of the document that i want to create ?

```
      const userProjectsColRef = collection(db, 'users');
      const newProjectDocRef = await addDoc(
        userProjectsColRef,
        generalData
      );
```

Comment: You need to use `setDoc()` to specify document ID yourself. Check the linked answer for more information.

Comment: I think this will work thank you !